# NSDecimalNumber crash if null

Tags: objective-c, initialization, nsdecimalnumber

I'm going crazy with this problem. If you try to do some operation on a NSDecimalNumber and you didn't initialize it, it cause a crash. The main problem is that if you initialize it in a part of your code, but then you use it in another part, you have always need to check is initialization status.

You can init all your NSDecimalNumber in the viewDidLoad or wherever your file start, but I feel that there must be another simpler way. Apple discourage subclassing the system method, so what is the best way to avoid these kind of crashes? Do you really have to always check?

Example:

```
NSDecimalNumber *x = [NSDecimalNumber zero];
NSDecimalNumber *y;

[x decimalNumberByAdding:y];
```

This crash because y is not initialized. This seems obvious, but if x is declared at the top of your code and you init it only where you need it the first time, you risk to use it elsewhere before it's initialization.

I'd like something that take ZERO as the default of non initialized NSDecimalNumber(s)

Comment: It can't crash, calling methods from `nil` is safe in `objective-c`. P.S. you just need to run static analyzer.

Comment: @Cy-4AH Fixed the example to let you understand better why it does crash

Comment: You have found one of the problems of Objective-C and similar low level languages. Make sure you always initialize variables. You need to keep your programming style very strict and avoid such problems using architecture and good coding practices. Or move to Swift where similar problems don't exist.

Comment: P.S. you just need to run static analyzer